# Removing negative values from the image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have an image and after performing a level of preprocessing, I observed that there are large number of negative values which are randomly located in the image.

Is there any way to remove those negative values not by zero but by some averaging operations in MATLAB?

**requirement**: My image should not be highly distorted after applying the operation.

Comment: please post some code with your image

Comment: I think if you have negative values, then your image is already distorted.

Comment: @Benoit_11 @AndrasDeak, the image is not distorted, however by applying certain formula, I have obtained negative values. I have not yet made the code but I believe that `filtering operation` would work.

Comment: question : does it seems logical that your image could countain negative value (what type of operations are you applying on your image) ? because you say 'i observe', but we don't know if it is supposed to happen

Comment: Post the code that is introducing the negative values (the *minimal* code, please) and a sample image to reproduce the error.

Comment: Negative values is **not** distortion.  "Distortion" has a very specific meaning in optics and imaging, referring to coordinate mapping problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: as suggested in comments, try to find out *why* you have negative values. Then decide, if you want these values. If yes: rescale the image to `[0,1]`. If you still want to remove these pixels and replace them by some average, as you suggested in the question, here's a way:

Such noise is called "Salt & Pepper Noise". The reason for this funny name is obvious, once you see an image of it: there are white (pixel = 1) and black (pixel = 0) dots all over the image, which looks like grains of salt and pepper.

[image: Salt & Pepper Noise]

In your case, if we assume that negative values are zero, you'll only have pepper noise in the image.

To solve that, let's prepare some data: We read the cameraman image and convert it to double (to allow for negative values). Then we randomly invert 1% of all pixels, so they are negative.

```
im = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
randmask = rand(size(im)) < 0.01;
distIm = im - 2*randmask.*im;
```

A simple and effective way to filter salt & pepper noise, 
is to use a median filter ([`medfilt2`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html)), which 
replaces each pixel in the image with the median value of a defined neighborhood, e.g. 3x3. This filter is one of your standard weapons against salt & pepper noise.

```
medfilt2(distIm);
```

You can even select the pixels which are smaller than zero, and apply the filter only to these, using the [`roifilt2`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/roifilt2.html) function. That way you don't touch the "correct" pixels:

```
filtIm = roifilt2(distIm, distIm<0, @medfilt2);
```

[image: result]

Doesn't look that bad, does it? But caution: if you have large regions of negative pixels, then this won't work that well, as the median of this neighborhood will still be negative.

Comment: Thank you so much for this effective illustration. Thank you once again. I could learn many things from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your image to `uint8` using  `im2uint8(I)` your image will be scaled.